# Stream text scanning

Tags: c#, strings, search, stream

I've written some utilities to read text from streams. One of these, the `ReadTo` method, is to read text from a specified stream until a given text is encountered, behaving like `string.IndexOf`, but with streams.
Really, it's quite fast. But I'd like to know if anyone knows any way to make it even faster, as it's used in a very performance-critical part of a program I'm developing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides utilities to manage streams.
/// </summary>
public static class StreamUtils
{

    private const int DefaultBufferSize = 1024;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate buffers from a specified stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of each buffer.</param>
    /// <param name="count">How many bytes to read. Negative values mean read to end.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static IEnumerable<byte[]> EnumerateBuffers(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize, long count = -1)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        do
        {
            long read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if (read < 1)
                break;
            if (count > -1)
            {
                count -= read;
                if (count < 0)
                    read += count;
            }
            if (read == bufferSize)
                yield return buffer;
            else
            {
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[read];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, (int)read);
                yield return newBuffer;
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate substrings from a specified stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The length of each substring.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSubstrings(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize) => stream.EnumerateSubstrings(Encoding.Default, bufferSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate substrings from a specified stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read.</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">The encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The length of each substring.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSubstrings(this Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize) => from byte[] buffer in stream.EnumerateBuffers(bufferSize) select encoding.GetString(buffer);

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the current stream until a specified string is encountered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The source stream.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The string that marks the end.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of the buffers.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static string ReadTo(this Stream stream, string separator, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize) => stream.ReadTo(separator, Encoding.Default, bufferSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the current stream until a specified string is encountered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The source stream.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The string that marks the end.</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">The encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of the buffers.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static string ReadTo(this Stream stream, string separator, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize)
    {
        // This method requires seeking, so ensure that the specified stream supports it.
        if (!stream.CanSeek)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        // This StringBuilder will build the resulting text. Using this to avoid too many string reallocations.
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        bool hasSuffix = false;
        string endingSeparator = null;
        // Retrieve how many bytes is the specified separator long. This will be necessary to handle some seekings on the stream.
        int separatorByteLength = encoding.GetByteCount(separator);
        // Iterate through each substring in the stream. Each one is a buffer converted to a string using a specified encoding.
        foreach (string substring in stream.EnumerateSubstrings(encoding, bufferSize))
        {
            // Retrieve how many bytes is the current substring long. Again, useful for seekings.
            int substringByteLength = encoding.GetByteCount(substring);
            // Check out whether the previous substring had a suffix.
            if (hasSuffix)
            {
                // If it had, then verify whether the current substring starts with the remaining part of the separator.
                if (substring.StartsWith(separator.Substring(endingSeparator.Length)))
                {
                    // In that case, seek till before the separator and break the loop.
                    stream.Seek(substringByteLength - encoding.GetByteCount(endingSeparator), SeekOrigin.Current);
                    break;
                }
                // If the code reached here, then the previous suffix were not part of a separator, as the whole of the separator cannot be found.
                hasSuffix = false;
                text.Append(endingSeparator);
            }
            // If the current substring starts with the separator, just skip it and break the loop, so the StringBuilder will only contain previous substrings.
            if (substring.StartsWith(separator))
                break;
            {
                // Check out whether the current substring contains the separator.
                int separatorIndex = substring.IndexOf(separator);
                if (separatorIndex != -1)
                {
                    // If that's the case, take this substring till the previously found index, ...
                    string newSubstring = substring.Remove(separatorIndex);
                    // ...then seek the current stream before the separator, ...
                    stream.Seek(encoding.GetByteCount(newSubstring) - substringByteLength, SeekOrigin.Current);
                    /// ...and finally append the new substring (the one before the separator) to the StringBuilder.
                    text.Append(newSubstring);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Check out whether the current substring ends with the specified separator.
            if (substring.EndsWith(separator))
            {
                // If it does, go back as many bytes as the separator is long within the stream.
                stream.Seek(-separatorByteLength, SeekOrigin.Current);
                // Then, append this substring till before the specified separator to the StringBuilder.
                text.Append(substring.Remove(substring.Length - separator.Length));
                break;
            }
            // Sometimes, it might happen that the separator is divided between the current substring and the next one.
            // So, see whether the current substring ends with just one part (even one only character) of the separator.
            endingSeparator = separator;
            do
                // Remove the last character from the 'ending separator'.
                endingSeparator = endingSeparator.Remove(endingSeparator.Length - 1);
                // If the ending separator isn't empty yet and the current substring doesn't end with it,
                // continue the loop.
            while (!(endingSeparator.Length == 0 || substring.EndsWith(endingSeparator)));
            // At this time, the ending separator will be an initial part of the specified separator,
            // which is a 'suffix' of the current substring.
            // Push the length of the suffix on the stack, so I'll avoid to call the Length getter accessor multiple times.
            int suffixLength = endingSeparator.Length;
            // If the suffix is empty, that means the current string doesn't end with even just a part of the separator.
            // Therefore, just append the current string to the StringBuilder.
            if (suffixLength == 0)
                text.Append(substring);
            else
            {
                // If rather the suffix isn't empty, then mark this with the boolean hasSuffix and
                // append the current substring only till before the suffix.
                hasSuffix = true;
                text.Append(substring.Remove(substring.Length - suffixLength));
            }
        }
        return text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
string text = "Hello world, this is a test";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(text)))
{
    string substring = stream.ReadTo(", this", encoding);
    // substring == "Hello world"
}
```

Comment: You must not edit the code when answers have been posted. It can and usually does invalidate them. I rolled back your last couple of edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By altering/ specifying the string comparer from the default StringComparison.CurrentCulture to StringComparison.Ordinal you can win a lot.

Also note that sometimes Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, (int)read) is slower than Array.Copy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, (int)read).

I ran your code with a Stopwatch, added these small changes and ran it as few times  again and again and averaged on.
original 401986 ticks
updated  101224 ticks

If you like to really know if you gain something instrument it with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/), cool nuget package that shows where "it hurts"

This is by no means all you could do, I would start to look at removing things that cause "newing up classes" as that takes a lot of time and work with span or even ReadOnlySpan. The linq method you use is such class that generates a class in memory that needs to be taken to the GC, over time this starts to slow things down.

Here is your code with the small tweeks

```
public static class StreamUtils
{

    private const int DefaultBufferSize = 1024;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate buffers from a specified stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of each buffer.</param>
    /// <param name="count">How many bytes to read. Negative values mean read to end.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static IEnumerable<byte[]> EnumerateBuffers(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize, long count = -1)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        do
        {
            long read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if (read < 1)
                break;
            if (count > -1)
            {
                count -= read;
                if (count < 0)
                    read += count;
            }
            if (read == bufferSize)
                yield return buffer;
            else
            {
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[read];
                Array.Copy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, (int)read);
                //Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, (int)read);
                yield return newBuffer;
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

        // A very simple and efficient memmove that assumes all of the
        // parameter validation has already been done.  The count and offset
        // parameters here are in bytes.  If you want to use traditional
        // array element indices and counts, use Array.Copy.
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        internal static extern void InternalBlockCopy(Array src, int srcOffsetBytes,
            Array dst, int dstOffsetBytes, int byteCount);


        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerate substrings from a specified stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream to read.</param>
        /// <param name="bufferSize">The length of each substring.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
        public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSubstrings(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize) 
            => stream.EnumerateSubstrings(Encoding.Default, bufferSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate substrings from a specified stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read.</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">The encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The length of each substring.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSubstrings(this Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize) 
            => from byte[] buffer in stream.EnumerateBuffers(bufferSize) select encoding.GetString(buffer);



    /// <summary>
    /// Read the current stream until a specified string is encountered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The source stream.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The string that marks the end.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of the buffers.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static string ReadTo(this Stream stream, string separator, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize) => stream.ReadTo(separator, Encoding.Default, bufferSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the current stream until a specified string is encountered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The source stream.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The string that marks the end.</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">The encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of the buffers.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="DecoderFallbackException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    public static string ReadTo(this Stream stream, string separator, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize)
    {
        // This method requires seeking, so ensure that the specified stream supports it.
        if (!stream.CanSeek)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        // This StringBuilder will build the resulting text. Using this to avoid too many string reallocations.
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        bool hasSuffix = false;
        string endingSeparator = null;
        // Retrieve how many bytes is the specified separator long. This will be necessary to handle some seekings on the stream.
        int separatorByteLength = encoding.GetByteCount(separator);
        // Iterate through each substring in the stream. Each one is a buffer converted to a string using a specified encoding.
        foreach (string substring in stream.EnumerateSubstrings(encoding, bufferSize))
        {
            // Retrieve how many bytes is the current substring long. Again, useful for seekings.
            int substringByteLength = encoding.GetByteCount(substring);
            // Check out whether the previous substring had a suffix.
            if (hasSuffix)
            {
                // If it had, then verify whether the current substring starts with the remaining part of the separator.
                if (substring.StartsWith(separator.Substring(endingSeparator.Length),StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    // In that case, seek till before the separator and break the loop.
                    stream.Seek(substringByteLength - encoding.GetByteCount(endingSeparator), SeekOrigin.Current);
                    break;
                }
                // If the code reached here, then the previous suffix were not part of a separator, as the whole of the separator cannot be found.
                hasSuffix = false;
                text.Append(endingSeparator);
            }
            // If the current substring starts with the separator, just skip it and break the loop, so the StringBuilder will only contain previous substrings.
            if (substring.StartsWith(separator,StringComparison.Ordinal))
                break;
            {
                // Check out whether the current substring contains the separator.
                int separatorIndex = substring.IndexOf(separator,StringComparison.Ordinal);
                if (separatorIndex != -1)
                {
                    // If that's the case, take this substring till the previously found index, ...
                    string newSubstring = substring.Remove(separatorIndex);
                    // ...then seek the current stream before the separator, ...
                    stream.Seek(encoding.GetByteCount(newSubstring) - substringByteLength, SeekOrigin.Current);
                    /// ...and finally append the new substring (the one before the separator) to the StringBuilder.
                    text.Append(newSubstring);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Check out whether the current substring ends with the specified separator.
            if (substring.EndsWith(separator,StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                // If it does, go back as many bytes as the separator is long within the stream.
                stream.Seek(-separatorByteLength, SeekOrigin.Current);
                // Then, append this substring till before the specified separator to the StringBuilder.
                text.Append(substring.Remove(substring.Length - separator.Length));
                break;
            }
            // Sometimes, it might happen that the separator is divided between the current substring and the next one.
            // So, see whether the current substring ends with just one part (even one only character) of the separator.
            endingSeparator = separator;
            do
                // Remove the last character from the 'ending separator'.
                endingSeparator = endingSeparator.Remove(endingSeparator.Length - 1);
                // If the ending separator isn't empty yet and the current substring doesn't end with it,
                // continue the loop.
            while (!(endingSeparator.Length == 0 || substring.EndsWith(endingSeparator,StringComparison.Ordinal)));
            // At this time, the ending separator will be an initial part of the specified separator,
            // which is a 'suffix' of the current substring.
            // Push the length of the suffix on the stack, so I'll avoid to call the Length getter accessor multiple times.
            int suffixLength = endingSeparator.Length;
            // If the suffix is empty, that means the current string doesn't end with even just a part of the separator.
            // Therefore, just append the current string to the StringBuilder.
            if (suffixLength == 0)
                text.Append(substring);
            else
            {
                // If rather the suffix isn't empty, then mark this with the boolean hasSuffix and
                // append the current substring only till before the suffix.
                hasSuffix = true;
                text.Append(substring, 0, substring.Length - suffixLength);
            }
        }
        return text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: _sometimes Buffer.BlockCopy is slower than Array.Copy_ - can you provide some information to support this so far theory? OP should use `ReadOnlySpan` in place of what exactly?

Comment: _BenchmarkDotNet, cool nuget package that shows where "it hurts"_ - by doing what? Is it better than a profiler?

Comment: @t3chb01, Well it's a different tool, shows different information. I like it when I tune code have a look at the documentation https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Answer (score 3):

#### Problems:

- `EnumerateSubstrings` and `ReadTo` do not work correctly with variable-width encodings, multi-byte encodings and surrogate pairs, because they do not take into account that characters can be split across buffer boundaries. This can cause a variety of problems.
- In some cases, `ReadTo` fails to find the separator if it's longer than the buffer size (this always happens if the separator is more than twice as long).
- `ReadTo` also fails to detect matches across buffer boundaries when `separator` contains a prefix of itself and there's both a partial and a full match across the boundary. For example, try reading up to `"aab"` in `"..aaab.."` with a buffer size of 4.

#### Performance:

- As has been pointed out already, `StringComparison.Ordinal` is a lot faster - because it just compares code point values without taking culture-specific rules into account. For example, a culture-aware comparison will see that `"\u00E9"` and `"e\u0301"` both represent an `é`, but an ordinal comparison will treat them as unequal. Which one to choose first and foremost depends on the behavior you need.
- The `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` checks are useless - `substring.IndexOf(separator)` already takes care of those situations.
- For long separators, the `do-while` loop that checks if the buffer ends with a prefix of the given separator involves a fair amount of string allocations. If you need culture-specific string comparisons then it might be faster to combine the end of the last buffer with the current buffer so you can keep using `IndexOf`. If ordinal comparisons are fine for your purposes, then a modified Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm could be useful here. Both of these should also help with solving the cross-boundary partial matches problem.
- Using an 8KB buffer is roughly 25% faster on my system. I'd recommend testing different sizes before deciding on a good (default) size.
- Instead of first creating a substring with `string.Remove`, use the `StringBuilder.Append(string, int, int)` overload.

#### Other notes:

- The encoding returned by `Encoding.Default` depends on system settings, which means you can get different results on different systems. `Encoding.UTF8` would be a safer default.
- It would be nice if the `NotSupportedException` exception contained a message that said what exactly it doesn't support.
- If you're going to guard against invalid parameters, then also be sure to check that the separator isn't null or empty. I'd also set the encoding and buffer size to some sane default value if they're null or too low, respectively.
- `ReadTo` contains a lot of superfluous comments. For example, the first check already makes it obvious that the method requires seeking, and the whole purpose of a `StringBuilder` is to build up strings efficiently. Repeating that in comments is just adding clutter.
- I'd recommend using `var` to cut down on typename repetition.
- Add some empty lines to break up long parts of code and to make it easier to distinguish between different 'blocks' of code (such as unrelated if statements).
- Inconsistent use of braces makes it more difficult to see control flow, which makes it easier to make mistakes.
- It's good to see methods being documented. A few minor things: 'the length of each substring' sounds like it's measured in characters, but it's actually the number of bytes. 'The size of the buffers' suggests that the methods use multiple buffers internally, so I'd make that singular instead.

Comment: I updated the code in my question as per some of your and other's suggestions. However, I cannot figure out how could some of your points be true: I've just noticed, as you pointed out, that my method would fail on if the specified separator is twice of more longer than the specified buffer size, but how could it fail on with separators just longer than the buffer size (less long than twice the buffer size).

Comment: The user @t3chb0t just rolled out my last changes. He was right, indeed. I was unaware of edits invalidating answers. Anyway, I don't understand how my method could fail on with separators that are longer than the buffer size and less long than twice it. Can you please explain me?

Comment: It happens when a match stretches across 3 buffers, which can be achieved with a separator that's `bufferSize + 2` long. Try finding `"abbbbc"` in `"aaaabbbbcccc"`, with a buffer size of 4.

Comment: I got that. I was referring to the case where the separator is longer than the buffer size, but shorter than twice as long.

Comment: `"abbbbc"` is longer than 4, but shorter than 8.

Comment: Right. I'll try to debug it as soon as possible.

Comment: I just debugged it, @Pieter Witvoet, and I'm trying to solve the issue.

Comment: I now fixed all the issues related to the length of the separator.

Comment: Why wouldn't my method work with variable-width encoding? I repeatedly used encoding.GetByteCount to get the length of a text as per the specified encoding. Can you please explain it to me, @Pieter Witvoet?

Comment: That problem has to do with `EnumerateSubstrings`. Try calling it on `"你好世界"` (UTF-8 encoded) with a buffer size of 4. Or try it on a UTF-16 encoded string while using an odd buffer size.

Comment: Thanks, @Pieter Witvoet for having pointed out such a bug. I just remembered I immediately thought of it when writing that method, without even having to test it out, but I couldn't find any way to fix it and then I forgot it. Do you have any idea to make that method working?

Comment: I just found a trick that I admit it's not the best solution, but which actually works: rather than using the specified buffer size, I'll use encoding.GetMaxByteCount(bufferSize)

Comment: Multiplying the buffer size won't solve the problem for variable-width encodings. If it weren't for the stream 'rewinding' I would've just used a `StreamReader` to take care of the buffering and decoding.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     if (read == bufferSize)
>       yield return buffer;
>     else
> ```

Be aware that repeatedly `yield return` the same buffer is rather risky. Imagine the following use case where all returned buffers are cached for later use for some reason:

```
  List<byte[]> buffers = new List<byte[]>();
  using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path))
  {
    foreach (byte[] buffer in stream.EnumerateBuffers(1024))
    {
      buffers.Add(buffer);
    }
  }
```

The result is that all items in `buffers` are references to the same buffer, hence they all have the same (the last returned with full length) set of bytes.

I think you should go with a much simpler approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> EnumerateBuffers(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize, long count = -1)
{
  long read;
  while (true)
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    if (read > 0)
      yield return buffer;
    else
      break;
  } 
}
```

---

**Update**

Have you tested performance against reading char-by-char using a `StreamReader`like:

```
public static string ReadTo(this Stream stream, string separator, Encoding encoding)
{
  if (!stream.CanSeek)
    throw new NotSupportedException("The stream must be seekable");

  StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
  int index = 0;
  bool searching = false;
  int sepIndex = 0;
  char cur;

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding, false, 1024, true))
  {
    int res;
    while ((res = reader.Read()) != -1)
    {
      cur = (char)res;
      if (!searching && cur == separator[0])
      {
        searching = true;
        sepIndex = 1;
      }
      else if (searching && sepIndex < separator.Length && cur == separator[sepIndex])
      {
        sepIndex++;
      }
      else
      {
        if (sepIndex == separator.Length)
        {
          break;
        }

        searching = false;
        sepIndex = 0;
      }

      text.Append(cur);

      index++;
    }
  }

  if (sepIndex == separator.Length && text.Length >= sepIndex)
    text.Length -= sepIndex;

  return text.ToString();
}
```

This is more than ten times faster than the original for a data set of 7600 kb and finding the last four chars as the `separator`.

Comment: I know that it is risky, but I need extreme performances, and re-allocating as many buffers as chunks would be even more risky when it comes to performances. My method is not meant to cache buffers, but to immediately read from a stream. Indeed, the right way to cache a stream is to copy it to a MemoryStream, not adding buffers to a list. It would be a bad practice, and if bad practices don't work, it's not my issue!

Comment: @DavideCannizzo: OK, it's your code, but maybe you should document the behavior then.

Comment: Right, @Henrik Hansen. I'll do as soon as possible

Comment: _a much simpler approach_ - could you explain what is so special about this approach?

Comment: @t3chb0t: It's you, that use the word "special" - not I. I call it simpler (than the original). But it is - according to Davides comment - irrelevant as he wants to keep his own version :-)

Comment: @Henrik Hansen, I agree with you that your way is much simpler, and it was the first thing that came up to my mind. However, I forgot to mention that I'm using these utilities with Sockets, and so, reading character by character would be extremely slow, as each character would be downloaded separately from the next ones. So, my approach was to work with buffers, which aim to be properly sized (but this is not a matter to discuss here - I already optimized the buffer sizes up), so that it can be as much fast as possible.

Comment: I'd like it if someone could speed up my idea or tell me about another that uses buffers as well. But your idea, which is optimal for most purposes, unfortunately, it's not the right one for my use case. I'll update my question to specify that I'm working with sockets. Regarding how streams could be related to Receive calls on the sockets, I use my own implementation of them (which, under the hood, uses the .NET standard implementation of sockets), which provides a stream to avoid Receive and Send calls.

Comment: However, thank you anyway for sharing your solution, @Henrik Hansen. I upvoted your answer for your contribution.

Comment: I think using span would be faster as you do not need to copy buffers at all

Answer (score 2):

If you're not scared of a little bit of `unsafe` code then you can get rid of the copying of the buffer entirely as there is a [`GetString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte__System_Int32_) overlaod that accepts a length of the buffer. Or [another overload](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) that doesn't require unsafe code

The loop in `ReadTo` could begin like this:

```
    foreach (var (buffer, length) in stream.EnumerateBuffers(bufferSize))
    {
        var substring = default(string);
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* p_buffer = buffer)
            {
                substring = encoding.GetString(p_buffer, length);
            }
        }   

        // or

        substring = encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
```

where `EnumerateBuffers` now returns tuples with the buffer and its length:

```
public static IEnumerable<(byte[] Buffer, int Length)> EnumerateBuffers(this Stream stream, int bufferSize = DefaultBufferSize, long count = -1)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    do
    {
        long read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        if (read < 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (count > -1)
        {
            count -= read;
            if (count < 0)
                read += count;
        }

        yield return (buffer, (int)read);

    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @t3chb0t for your solution. However, I won't apply it because of the disorder of returning tuples (I'm not scared of unsafety).

Comment: @DavideCannizzo sure, there is no _must apply_ ;-] I just thought it's good to know there is one more overload that makes it more convenient in certain situations - might be useful someone else. But could you expand what kind of _disorder_ you mean?

Comment: @DavideCannizzo I now noticed your edit. _disorder of returning tuples_? I might still need help understanding this one.

Comment: I'm happy to know about the overload you were pointing out (indeed, I upvoted your answer the same). However, I feel your code a bit messy. EnumerateSubstring, as per its name, should enumerate some substrings (each one per buffer), so it'll be strange if it returned tuples. Moreover, I made it to make things simple, and if it gave the responsibility to cut the buffers, it would be uncomfortable to use it.

Comment: @DavideCannizzo haha, now I see what you mean. It's just for demonstration purposes. It doesn't mean it _has to be_ implemented exactly like that. The point was the overload ;-) but... the other iterators _consume_ performance too, so in a perfomrance critical parts there is no or very little clean-code :P

Comment: @DavideCannizzo as a matter of fact I started this with the pointers and only later noticed there was the second overload. The reason it looks the way it is, is because enumerators didn't like unsafe code :-P Had I started with the _safe_ one, it'd probably turned out differently hehe.

Comment: Right, @t3chb0t. I didn't know about pointers not being able to be used in enumerator contexts as well. The second thing I learned with your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why in the past few weeks have tuples started appearing everywhere?!

Comment: @VisualMelon tuples for president! :-P